# videoFilter - draw text between one time and between another time

Tags: ffmpeg

Well I know we can use drawText for a time range using

> "enable=between(t, 1, 3)" (between 1 sec and 3sec)

but how can I add

> "and draw text between 45 sec to 50 sec".

I can't find out how to add another between condition.

Comment: Avoid crossposting the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites. You asked here [and at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1281017/videofilter-draw-text-between-one-time-and-between-another-time) resulting in two users spending their time to provide the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arithmetic operators:

```
"enable=between(t,1,3)+between(t,45,60)"
```

`+` corresponds to OR; `*` to AND.